# Prove that Gaussian Elimination affects eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given the eigenvalue problem below:
>
> $$Ax=\lambda x$$
>
> we know that guassian elimination affects the computation of eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

I am trying to prove this with math. So given an elementary matrix $L$ which for example subtracts a multiple of one row from another (gaussian elimination step):

$$LAx=\lambda Lx \iff A'x = \lambda x'$$

we expect to have a new eigen-analysis system with different eigenvalues and eigenvectors on both sides of equation. However, gaussian elimination changes $A$ and the eigenvector $x$ on the right side of equation while we were also expected to have a new $\lambda$ and $x$ on the left side of the equation.

Could you please cast some light on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Uh... *every* invertible matrix can be reduced by Gaussian elimination to an upper triangular matrix with 1's on the diagonal. The eigenvalues of the final matrix are all 1, of course.

Comment: Inspired from your comment, if $A=LDU$, where $L$ and $U$ have ones on the diagonal and D is a the diagonal matrix of pivots, then $D^{-1}L^{-1}Ax=\lambda D^{-1}L^{-1}x \iff Ux=\lambda x' = x''$. So, if gaussian elimination didn't change $x$ and $\lambda$ then we should have $Ux=x$ but that is impossible ($x \neq x''$).  In this way, we prove that gaussian elimination change both $\lambda$ (all ones) and $x$'. Am I right?